# Required Field Validator not working for JQuery chosen drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

I am using JQuery Choosen for my DropDownList but the required validator for that dropdown is not working . Following is my code .Please guide where i am wrong.

Chosen plugin included in the form

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

DropDownList code

```
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DepartmentId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DepartmentId, (ViewBag.DepartmentsList) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select an Option --",new { @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:312px; height:31px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DepartmentId)
</li>
```

And Model for the DropDownList

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Department Name")]
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
```

Comment: **[This link](http://utsavized.com/chosen-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-asp-net-mvc3/)** might help

Comment: @GuruprasadRao there is no dropdown at this link

Comment: Instead of `ListBox` there you can use your `dropdown`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao    i can't locate any help from that link ..please help with some code

Comment: Can you try creating a demo **[here](http://www.dotnetfiddle.net)**

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Is there an error?  How are you reproducing the problem?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 there is no error.But it is not showing required field validator error , that i want

Comment: You need to use .chosen().change( .. )

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 nothing happening with your answer

Comment: @Dimitri can you help in this regard

Comment: @GuruparasadRao@NotoriousPet0 , i have solved this problem and have created an answer for this..thanks all for you response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Chosen updates the html by making the original select hidden (style="Display:none"). By default jquery.validate (1.9.0) ignores hidden elements. You can override the default using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: []
});
```