# MVC Validations not working when deployed on IIS

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, iis

I have deployed an MVC project on IIS but not a single validation is working there while validations working fine at localhost.It shows an error that `.live()` is not a method, then I googled and replaced `.live()` with `.on()` so now that error is not showing but validations are still not working at all. Please guide me to tackle this issue. Following is my sample View Code

```
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountName)
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountId, (ViewBag.AccountsList) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "", @style = "width:312px; height:31px;" })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountId, (ViewBag.AccountsList) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @Id = "AccountName", @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:312px; height:31px; float: right;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountId)



            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactName)

            </li>
```

and following is the code of Model

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Account Name")]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Show an example of the code you claim is not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke please check my updated question

Comment: You model has property `AccountName` but your view is for `AccountId`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  , but others should work

Comment: There is nothing you have shown that indicates what the issue is. Are you loading the correct scripts? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: just check all your reference library are loaded

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have stated in my question that i was getting an error of .live() is not a method, but i replaced that and now i am not getting any error but the form is being submitted without any required validation error

Comment: Where were you using `.live()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it was in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: Then you are using obsolete scripts. Update them (jquery.js, jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) to the latest versions.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it works! thanks alot.......i have another problem that required validators are not working on chosen select dropdown even on my localhost, can you help in this regard

Comment: @User123, i have added an answer for this question, but you will need to ask as new question for the `chosen` select issue, and show the relevant code. I suspect its because `chosen` hides the original `<select>` tag and renders it's own html (and hidden elements are not validated by default), but would need to see the code to be sure. Also important to state which version of jquery your using.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here is the link to my question about chosen select http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445293/required-field-validator-not-working-for-jquery-chosen-drop-down-list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84981/discussion-between-user123-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated you have changed `.live()` with `.on()` suggesting you are using outdated scripts because `.live()` was depreciated in jquery v1.7 and removed in v1.9. You will need to update all scripts associated with unobtrusive client side validation - jquery{version}.js, jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to current versions.